# networkx drawing of edges on top of one another

Tags: python, networkx

I have data that looks like this:

```
parsed_points = [(u'USD', u'JPY', -4.566), (u'USD', u'USD', -0.0), (u'JPY', u'EUR', 4.821), (u'BTC', `u'USD', -4.91), (u'JPY', u'BTC', 9.361), (u'USD', u'EUR', 0.314), (u'EUR', u'USD', -0.117), (u'EUR', u'JPY', -4.746), (u'JPY', u'USD', 4.57), (u'BTC', u'BTC', -0.0), (u'EUR', u'BTC', 4.621), (u'BTC', u'JPY', -9.539), (u'JPY', u'JPY', -0.0), (u'BTC', u'EUR', -4.606), (u'EUR', u'EUR', -0.0), (u'USD', u'BTC', 4.854)]`
```

As can be seen there are nodes with edges coming from and going to each node. The problem is that when I draw the nodes with networkx, the edges are on top of one another:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
...

parsed_points = map(parse_point, obj.items())
dg = build_graph(parsed_points)

pos = nx.spring_layout(dg, k = 0.95, iterations = 150)

nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(dg, pos, edge_labels = edge_labels)
nx.draw(dg, pos, cmap = plt.get_cmap('jet'), node_color = values, node_size = 1500, edge_color = edge_colors, edge_cmap = plt.cm.Reds)
```

What is the solution to this problem? Perhaps use arcs instead of lines [if possible] for the edges?